# Create Temporary url for a Dynamic page in PHP

Tags: php

I am generating a php response to a post request as follows

```
<?php
ob_start();
include_once('includes/headers.php');
require_once('includes/connection.php');
require_once('includes/functions.php');
?>

<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
</head>
<?php
include($filePath);
?>
```

This works and is OK.

But I have a different use case.

I want to get the output of this page and create a page.

Then send the user the link to that page.

So the reponse will be a link only.

The page will be destroyed after the user is done with it and need not be stored.

How can this be done in PHP.

Comment: You mean, you want to store the result of the page and then show it to anyone having the good URL ?

Comment: yes..Not anyone the same user immediately. I am doing this because of the cordova inappbrowser which can only open a link and not a php response

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A straight forward technique to achieve what you want:

1. Use mod_rewirte and .htaccess to setup "pretty URLs"
2. Have an index.php to receive the requests and process them:
3. Create a hash key dynamically for each "page", store it in a database (e.g. MySQL).
4. The "special" URL will be constructed from your domain path and the hash key for each page (e.g. http://www.my-domain.com/pages/azXi39444)
5. When a user enters the URL, he will get the output that is related to the key that he has used in the URL, and the hash key will be deleted from the database (of flagged as "deleted")

So you create the page, build the URL (as mentioned above) - and send it back as a response to the user.

I will not get into how to setup mod_rewirte and .htaccess but here is a link to a simple guide:
https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/using-htaccess-files-for-pretty-urls--net-6049

An example of an .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url_params=$1 [L,QSA]
```

This can be a simple example of an index.php (pseudo code):

```
<?php
    $params = explode('/',$_GET['url_params']);
    $hash = $params[0];

    // not a real database adapter - but you get the idea..
    $db = new DatabaseAdapter('username','password','database');

    $result = $db->querySingle("SELECT pageFileName FROM tb_Pages WHERE hash = %1", $hash);

    if($result){

        // delete the used hash
        $db->query("DELETE FROM tb_Pages WHERE hash = %1", $hash);

        // include the path of the page for display
        include('/mySecretFolder/'.$result->pageFileName );

    }else{

        echo 'Page not found';
        exit;

    }
?>
```

If you want the pages to be completely virtual, you can ditch the concept of including actual files and store the pages content in a database table, then just pull the data from the database and display accordingly with the page hash\id that was given.

A pseudo example for a database table to store virtual pages:

```
CREATE TABLE tb_Pages
(
  PageID INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
  CreateDate Timestamp,
  HashKey VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  HtmlContent TEXT,
  INDEX(HashKey),
  PRIMARY KEY(PageID)
)ENGINE=InnoDB CHARACTER SET utf8;
```

With this approach you use the same concept of .htaccess, url rewrite, index.php and generated hash keys, but instead of including actual files - you are fetching the page content from the database and echo it.

Hope it helps a bit.